# Split AMEX Transaction detail strings using regex

Tags: php, regex, accounting

I have an array of transaction description strings from an American Express Card that I will be using PHP's `preg_split()` to parse;

```
[
  "THE DISNEY STORE #90DANBURY             CT",
  "CHRISTMAS TREE SHOPSDANBURY             CT",
  "BATH & BODY WORKS 07DANBURY             CT",
  "CITGO DODGINGTOWN GANEWTOWN             CT",
  "DUNKIN #344944 Q35 3MONROE              CT",
  "DUNKIN #344944 Q35 3MONROE              CT",
  "DUNKIN #344944 Q35 3MONROE              CT",
  "DUNKIN #344944 Q35 3MONROE              CT",
  "AT&T RECURR BILL PAYDALLAS              TX",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "POSTAGE REFILL      STAMFORD            CT",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "ONLINE PAYMENT - THANK YOU",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "AOL SERVICE         800-827-6364        VA",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "EBAY INC. 0000      866-779-3229        CA",
  "WWW.ITUNES.COM/BILL CUPERTINO           CA",
  "THE HOME DEPOT      TRUMBULL            CT",
  "THE HOME DEPOT      TRUMBULL            CT",
  "AMEX GIFT CARDS     866-268-0582        NY",
  "APPLE ONLINE STORE  CUPERTINO           CA",
  "APPLE ONLINE STORE  CUPERTINO           CA",
  "AMAZON MKTPLACE PMTSAMZN.COM/BILL       WA",
  "THE HOME DEPOT      BRIDGEPORT          CT",
  "AT&T RECURR BILL PAYDALLAS              TX",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "AT&T RECURR BILL PAYDALLAS              TX",
  "SHELL OIL 5754389960NEWTOWN             CT",
  "WALGREENS           NEWTOWN             CT",
  "THE HOME DEPOT      TRUMBULL            CT",
  "ONLINE PAYMENT - THANK YOU",
  "AOL SERVICE         800-827-6364        VA"
]
```

What I am attempting to do is parse the vendor city and state from the description string. This data is in a CSV that gets uploaded to a PHP script. Using the online tool [regexr.com](http://regexr.com) I have been able to get close using this expression:

```
([A-Z&0-9 ./#\*\-]{0,19})\w
```

What I was able to infer is a 20 characters max for a description, except in the case of payments then the text runs on. The city starts right at the 20 character limit and is allowed to contain whitespace in some cases. The state is 2 characters with preceding white space.

### Expected results:

```
CHRISTMAS TREE SHOPSDANBURY             CT
```

Would Parse to

*Vendor:* `CHRISTMAS TREE SHOPS`  *City:* `DANBURY`  *State:* `CT`

Payments;

```
ONLINE PAYMENT - THANK YOU
```

Would stay as is.

And edge cases;

```
AOL SERVICE         800-827-6364        VA
```

Would parse to

*Vendor:* `AOL SERVICE` *Detail:* `800-827-6364` *State:* `VA`

(*Labels* used for clarity)

### Actual Results:

if you look at my saved results https://regexr.com/3j39m you can see that lines like `ONLINE PAYMENT - THANK YOU` and `AOL SERVICE         800-827-6364        VA` don't parse as expected.

### How could I improve the expression to:

1. Parse the first 20 or fewer characters in the vendor/description.
2. Handle the payment description which lacks the 3 expected parts.
3. Handle cases when the vendor has substituted other information into the expected city location that may exceed the 20 character limit.

Comment: Your input seems to be fixed-width. Rege is not necessary (the best tool) here.

Comment: I'm open to any PHP solution at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a regex to split a fixed-width string like this:

```
<?php

$re = '/(?<Store>.{20})(?<City>.{20})(?<State>.{2})/m';
$str = 'THE DISNEY STORE #90DANBURY             CT';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

foreach( $matches as $match ){
    echo $match[1]."\t=>\t".$match[2]."\t=>\t".$match[3]."\n";
}
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/IohS2B/1).

You can achieve the same with `substr()`.

Comment: That works as expected, and will `preg_match_all()` pass false if there is no match?

Comment: Yes, correct. Plus, forgot `trim($text)`. You, are welcome.

Answer (score -1):

It looks to me as if the list is tab delimited, so this should do the trick: `/\t([A-Za-z ]+)\t+[A-Za-z]{2}$/`

Explanation

- `\t` match a tab
- `([A-Za-z ]+)` match a string of characters and spaces, signifying a town name
- `\t+` match one or more tabs (looks like it might be more than one in your data set)
- `[A-Za-z]{2}` match 2 characters, signifying a state abbreviation
- `$` end of string